# Rename columns in data frame in Python

Tags: python

I've completed an analysis and convert results into a data frame using result.to_frame(). And the result looks like this:

[image]

The next step is to build a pivotal table based on column 1 and sum the counts. In order to do that, I want to label the first column as "query". I used this code, but the first column cannot be renamed.

```
df.rename(columns = {'query':'sum of counts'}, inplace = True)
```

I found it shows this data frame only has one column even though I saw two.

[image]

Comment: `df.rename(columns = {'query':'sum of counts'}` is backwards, switch the positions of `query` & `sum of counts` if you're trying to name it `query`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  you indeed have 1 column, and the description is actually your index. If your DataFrame is "df", try the following:

```
df.shape # this should show (N, 1) where N is the number of records
df['Query'] = df.index # to pull a copy of the index into a column
```

You should be able to proceed normally then.